# Obtener backgroundColor de un div al hacer click (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, css

Estoy haciendo un pequeño juego de una paleta de dibujo trabajando con el DOM de JavaScript. Quiero que al pinchar en cada div con un color de fondo, se seleccione ese color.

No sé que estoy haciendo mal, porque al acceder a la propiedad `style.backgroundColor`, no me devuelve ningún valor, **¿cómo puedo acceder al backgroundColor del div en el que hago click?**

Mi código es el siguiente, podéis ejecutarlo para ver lo que digo. lo muestro en unos "alert" para que se entienda mejor.

```js
function generarLienzo(){
    var cuerpo=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var contenedor=document.createElement("div");
    //TITULO
    contenedor.setAttribute("id","contenedor");
    var titulo=document.createElement("h1");
    var textoTitulo=document.createTextNode("Tablero de Dibujo");
    var textoClic=document.createTextNode("Haga CLICK en un color para empezar a dibujar");
    titulo.appendChild(textoTitulo);
    
    contenedor.appendChild(titulo);
    contenedor.appendChild(textoClic);
    //PALETA
    var paleta=document.createElement("div");
    paleta.setAttribute("id","paleta");
   
    for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        var color=document.createElement("div");
        color.setAttribute("id","color"+i);
        color.setAttribute("class","color");
        color.addEventListener("click",function(){
                quitarSeleccionado();   
               this.className+=" seleccionado";   
               var seleccion=document.getElementById("seleccionar");
               //Aquí tengo el fallo, no sé cómo recoger backgroundColor
               var elemseleccionado = document.getElementsByClassName("seleccionado")[0];
               alert("Se ha seleccionado "+elemseleccionado);
               alert("Se ha seleccionado "+elemseleccionado.style.backgroundColor);
               alert(color.style.backgroundColor);
               
               seleccion.style.backgroundColor=color.style.backgroundColor;
               
        });
       
        paleta.appendChild(color);
        
    }
    var parrafo2=document.createElement("p");
    parrafo2.innerHTML="Estado del pincel:<span id='seleccionar' >Sin Seleccionar</span>";
    
    contenedor.appendChild(parrafo2);
    //TABLA
    var tabla=document.createElement("table");
    tabla.setAttribute("class","zonadibujo");
       var fila=document.createElement("tr");
    fila.setAttribute("class","filadibujo");
    for (var i = 0; i < 960; i++) {
       
      var celda=document.createElement("td");
    celda.setAttribute("class","celdadibujo");
    fila.appendChild(celda);
    
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
     tabla.appendChild(fila);
    }
   
    paleta.appendChild(tabla);
   contenedor.appendChild(paleta);
   cuerpo.appendChild(contenedor);
    
}
//EVENTOS
function quitarSeleccionado(){
    var cajasColores= document.getElementsByClassName("color");
    for (var i = 0; i < cajasColores.length; i++) {
        cajasColores[i].classList.remove("seleccionado");//para quitar la clase,sin quitar las demas
        //cajasColores[i].setAttribute("class","color");
    }
}


window.onload=function(){
   
    generarLienzo();
    var contenedor=document.getElementById("contenedor");
  
}
```

```css
@font-face{
 font-family: Roboto;
 src:url("fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
}


*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
 height:100%;
}

body{
 font-family: Roboto;
 background-image:url("img/brush.jpg");
 margin:0px;
 height: 100%;
}

h1{
 margin-top:0px; 
}

/* Contenedor del tablero */

#contenedor{
 width:600px;
 text-align:center;
 margin:0 auto;
 background-color:#D6D6D6;
 border-left:5px solid black;
 border-right:5px solid black;
 padding-top:10px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
}

/* Contiene la paleta de color */

#paleta{
 margin:0 auto;
}

/* Clase común a cada caja de color */

.color{
 width: 80px;
 height: 50px;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:10px;
 border:medium solid transparent;
}

/* Ids correspondientes a cada uno de los colores */

#color1 {
 background-color: #F00;
}

#color2 {
 background-color: #0F0;
}

#color3 {
 background-color: #00F;
}

#color4 {
 background-color: #FF0;
}

#color5 {
 background-color: #0FF;
}

#color6 {
 background-color: #FFF;
}


/* Paleta de color seleccionada */
.seleccionado{
 border: 5px solid #000000;
}


/* Tablero de dibujo */
.zonadibujo{
 display:inline-block;
 
}

/* Cada fila del tablero de dibujo */
.filadibujo{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 height:12px;
}

/* Cada celda del tablero de dibujo */
.celdadibujo {
 width: 10px;
 height:10px;
 margin: 1px;
 padding: 0px;
 background-color:white;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El problema ocurre debido a que `ele.style` devuelve los estilos aplicados `en linea`(`eg: <div style="..."`).

Dado que los estilos para los `div` son asignados mediante `CSS` a través del `id` asignado, una solución es usar la API [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

### Demo:

```js
function generarLienzo() {
  var cuerpo = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var contenedor = document.createElement("div");
  //TITULO
  contenedor.setAttribute("id", "contenedor");
  var titulo = document.createElement("h1");
  var textoTitulo = document.createTextNode("Tablero de Dibujo");
  var textoClic = document.createTextNode("Haga CLICK en un color para empezar a dibujar");
  titulo.appendChild(textoTitulo);

  contenedor.appendChild(titulo);
  contenedor.appendChild(textoClic);
  //PALETA
  var paleta = document.createElement("div");
  paleta.setAttribute("id", "paleta");

  for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    var color = document.createElement("div");
    color.setAttribute("id", "color" + i);
    color.setAttribute("class", "color");
    color.addEventListener("click", function() {
      quitarSeleccionado();
      this.classList.add("seleccionado");
      var seleccion = document.getElementById("seleccionar");
      seleccion.style.backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(this).backgroundColor;
    });

    paleta.appendChild(color);

  }
  var parrafo2 = document.createElement("p");
  parrafo2.innerHTML = "Estado del pincel:<span id='seleccionar' >Sin Seleccionar</span>";

  contenedor.appendChild(parrafo2);
  //TABLA
  var tabla = document.createElement("table");
  tabla.setAttribute("class", "zonadibujo");
  var fila = document.createElement("tr");
  fila.setAttribute("class", "filadibujo");
  for (var i = 0; i < 960; i++) {

    var celda = document.createElement("td");
    celda.setAttribute("class", "celdadibujo");
    fila.appendChild(celda);

  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    tabla.appendChild(fila);
  }

  paleta.appendChild(tabla);
  contenedor.appendChild(paleta);
  cuerpo.appendChild(contenedor);

}
//EVENTOS
function quitarSeleccionado() {
  var cajasColores = document.getElementsByClassName("color");
  for (var i = 0; i < cajasColores.length; i++) {
    cajasColores[i].classList.remove("seleccionado"); //para quitar la clase,sin quitar las demas
    //cajasColores[i].setAttribute("class","color");
  }
}


window.onload = function() {

  generarLienzo();
  var contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor");

}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  src: url("fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  background-image: url("img/brush.jpg");
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0px;
}


/* Contenedor del tablero */

#contenedor {
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #D6D6D6;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}


/* Contiene la paleta de color */

#paleta {
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Clase común a cada caja de color */

.color {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: medium solid transparent;
}


/* Ids correspondientes a cada uno de los colores */

#color1 {
  background-color: #F00;
}

#color2 {
  background-color: #0F0;
}

#color3 {
  background-color: #00F;
}

#color4 {
  background-color: #FF0;
}

#color5 {
  background-color: #0FF;
}

#color6 {
  background-color: #FFF;
}


/* Paleta de color seleccionada */

.seleccionado {
  border: 5px solid #000000;
}


/* Tablero de dibujo */

.zonadibujo {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Cada fila del tablero de dibujo */

.filadibujo {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 12px;
}


/* Cada celda del tablero de dibujo */

.celdadibujo {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!! Buena explicación y funciona perfecto

Answer (score 3):

Usa el método `getComputedStyle()`

```js
function generarLienzo(){
    var cuerpo=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var contenedor=document.createElement("div");
    //TITULO
    contenedor.setAttribute("id","contenedor");
    var titulo=document.createElement("h1");
    var textoTitulo=document.createTextNode("Tablero de Dibujo");
    var textoClic=document.createTextNode("Haga CLICK en un color para empezar a dibujar");
    titulo.appendChild(textoTitulo);
    
    contenedor.appendChild(titulo);
    contenedor.appendChild(textoClic);
    //PALETA
    var paleta=document.createElement("div");
    paleta.setAttribute("id","paleta");
   
    for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        var color=document.createElement("div");
        color.setAttribute("id","color"+i);
        color.setAttribute("class","color");
        color.addEventListener("click",function(){
                quitarSeleccionado();   
               this.className+=" seleccionado";   
               var seleccion=document.getElementById("seleccionar");
               //Aquí tengo el fallo, no sé cómo recoger backgroundColor
               var elemseleccionado = document.getElementsByClassName("seleccionado")[0];
//MODIFICACIÓN
               alert("Se ha seleccionado "+ getComputedStyle(elemseleccionado, null)["backgroundColor"] );
//FIN DE MODIFICACIÓN
               
               seleccion.style.backgroundColor=color.style.backgroundColor;
               
        });
       
        paleta.appendChild(color);
        
    }
    var parrafo2=document.createElement("p");
    parrafo2.innerHTML="Estado del pincel:<span id='seleccionar' >Sin Seleccionar</span>";
    
    contenedor.appendChild(parrafo2);
    //TABLA
    var tabla=document.createElement("table");
    tabla.setAttribute("class","zonadibujo");
       var fila=document.createElement("tr");
    fila.setAttribute("class","filadibujo");
    for (var i = 0; i < 960; i++) {
       
      var celda=document.createElement("td");
    celda.setAttribute("class","celdadibujo");
    fila.appendChild(celda);
    
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
     tabla.appendChild(fila);
    }
   
    paleta.appendChild(tabla);
   contenedor.appendChild(paleta);
   cuerpo.appendChild(contenedor);
    
}
//EVENTOS
function quitarSeleccionado(){
    var cajasColores= document.getElementsByClassName("color");
    for (var i = 0; i < cajasColores.length; i++) {
        cajasColores[i].classList.remove("seleccionado");//para quitar la clase,sin quitar las demas
        //cajasColores[i].setAttribute("class","color");
    }
}


window.onload=function(){
   
    generarLienzo();
    var contenedor=document.getElementById("contenedor");
  
}
```

```css
@font-face{
 font-family: Roboto;
 src:url("fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
}


*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
 height:100%;
}

body{
 font-family: Roboto;
 background-image:url("img/brush.jpg");
 margin:0px;
 height: 100%;
}

h1{
 margin-top:0px; 
}

/* Contenedor del tablero */

#contenedor{
 width:600px;
 text-align:center;
 margin:0 auto;
 background-color:#D6D6D6;
 border-left:5px solid black;
 border-right:5px solid black;
 padding-top:10px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
}

/* Contiene la paleta de color */

#paleta{
 margin:0 auto;
}

/* Clase común a cada caja de color */

.color{
 width: 80px;
 height: 50px;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:10px;
 border:medium solid transparent;
}

/* Ids correspondientes a cada uno de los colores */

#color1 {
 background-color: #F00;
}

#color2 {
 background-color: #0F0;
}

#color3 {
 background-color: #00F;
}

#color4 {
 background-color: #FF0;
}

#color5 {
 background-color: #0FF;
}

#color6 {
 background-color: #FFF;
}


/* Paleta de color seleccionada */
.seleccionado{
 border: 5px solid #000000;
}


/* Tablero de dibujo */
.zonadibujo{
 display:inline-block;
 
}

/* Cada fila del tablero de dibujo */
.filadibujo{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 height:12px;
}

/* Cada celda del tablero de dibujo */
.celdadibujo {
 width: 10px;
 height:10px;
 margin: 1px;
 padding: 0px;
 background-color:white;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: La respuesta es correcta, pero podrías explicar el por qué `style.backgroundColor` está vacío y por qué getComputedStyle() funciona

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! Funciona perfecto, me faltó completar la explicación pero el resto genial, te lo agradezco

Comment: Perdón. La propiedad `style` hace referencia al `style` (valga la redundancia) del elemento y no a la que le viene dada por css.